# Running one bat file in command line in order to setup a MongoDB replica set

Tags: mongodb, batch-file

How to cause the following commands present in bat file to open in different cmd windows and be run there?

```
mongod.exe --port 61123 --dbpath D:\data\rs0 --replSet test
mongod.exe --port 61124 --dbpath D:\data\rs1 --replSet test
mongod.exe --port 61125 --dbpath D:\data\rs2 --replSet test
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start "" mongod.exe --port 61123 --dbpath D:\data\rs0 --replSet test
start "" mongod.exe --port 61124 --dbpath D:\data\rs1 --replSet test
start "" mongod.exe --port 61125 --dbpath D:\data\rs2 --replSet test
```

Comment: do you get any error?What happens? This should start the mongo db in three separate windows.At least works for me.